# Ranking questions on REDCap

Tags: matrix, ranking, redcap

We have a matrix of questions with 12 field label variable (resources) and options for this matrix are - Strongly disagree -to strongly agree. I want  develop next question based on "Strongly agree answer' and asking participants to rank those variable/sources.

'The final set of questions relate to return to work resources the MDT team may have offered while you were still in the recovery unit. Please indicate how much you agree with the following statements.'

1 Help with CV

2 Apply funding .....

3

......

12 Adaptive equipment

For the following question - is it possible to pull out variables/ resources that participant choose as strongly agreed and ask them to rank them 1 to 5.

Thanks,
JM

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a matrix of 12 fields with strongly agree to strongly disagree, and for each of those that are marked strongly agree, you want to have the respondent rank them from 1 through to 5.

What you can do is have another matrix field that asks respondents to select a choice between 1 and 5 for each of the 12 statements in the first matrix. Then, for each statement in the second matrix, add branching logic to only show it if the corresponding statement in the first matrix was strongly agree. Finally, set the matrix to 'Ranking'; this will only allow a single response per column (in addition to only a single response per row). This will mean a user may only have one 1, one 2, etc.,

Here's what that looks like in the designer:

[image: ranking matrix]

However, there are problems with this. First, there is nothing to prevent someone selecting strongly agree to more than 5 choices, meaning there will be statements that cannot be ranked. Maybe this is good; maybe you only want them to be able to rank 5 and the way to handle that is to only provide 5 columns to rank. Here's a screenshot of a record with 6 statements to rank. Notice the last cannot be ranked or it will displace another statement's ranking:

[image]

The reverse is also true, if someone answers strongly agree to less than 5 statements, they will still see 5 columns to rank the less than 5 statements, so you might have 1, 2, 3, or it might be 1, 3, 4. This screenshot shows three statements being ranked, leaving two rank positions unfilled.

[image]

The problem is that the number of choices in a ranking matrix field cannot grow or shrink depending on the number of statements in it.